# PHP - my CMS security

Tags: php, security

I have my own cms, I'm exploring the security options which I should implement and study.

All my CMS pages are checking of user permissions based on the UserID stored in Session. I was thinking that how much important is it for me to "secure" the forms inside this pages? I mean the users have the opportunity to write SQL statements so if they would want to like use SQL injections it is not really that hard...

So my thinking is to have only the logon page secured + protection against session hijacking, is that correct or am I missing something?

Forms on the front page, query strings etc are also secured.

Thank you for any inside on this.

Comment: Define "secured" in terms of forms. I'll write a generic answer, and when your details come in, I'll add specifics.

Comment: thanks for the really fast input. I dont have it implemented yet, but in terms of login page securing im thinking on the escaping html characters, quotes and parametrizing SQL statement. I dont know much about session hijacking so I will need to learn that. I just hope that if I have Login page secured + protection against hijacking its no way that someone can get access to my cms pages - everysingle one of the is checking permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Securing web apps is a never-ending task. People find vectors to exploit every day (quite literally) through a combination of tools and methods. When building a CMS, you've got to be particularly careful with:

- Users being able to log in as someone who they are not
- Users being able to remotely inject **permanently** into a page (especially when combined with above)
- Users being able to modify or extract contents of the database they are not supposed to gain access to

All these have to do with form submission, or more generally, userdata entry. It boils down to one simple precept: never **ever** trust an user.

The first one you have to worry about, and by far the most dangerous, is SQL injection. It's what a lot of companies fall victim to every year, and it is quite in-depth, though most attacks can be prevented by using parametrized queries (*TRUE* parametrized queries. PDO by default emulates them, there's a config flag to turn on true parametrization). This will effectively do most of the SQL-relevant sanitization for you, leaving the "sensible sanitization" to you (i.e. making sure that a date is actually a date). This protects you from what people tend to call first-order SQL injection - in other words, direct entry.

Second-order is more difficult. It involves storing something in your database that will then get executed in another statement. The [CISCO](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/sql_injection.html#5) guide has a good idea of how stuff happens.

That's all for SQL to defeat the large majority of script-kiddies.

In terms of content-filtering, you want to use a whitelisting approach rather than a blacklisting one. Remove everything you do not trust or cannot recognize. In terms of HTML, there's a wonderful tool called HTMLPurify that does exactly this.

## Also

Don't make the mistake my boss did. Check for the session immediately, not just before rendering the page after the controller has run.

Comment: Thanks very much for the information. I have been going through the purify documentation, I was thinking of using it, but I decided not no because of the following reason -> User (we can more likely say editor, since only editors will have opportunity to do this) can write html code (such as page layout) in the CMS Desk. My thought was that editor/administrator can do literally anything, he can even delete the site in a matter of some clicks. What would be the reason for using html purify if the editors have full control on the site anyway?